# why is the app unable to run on my device?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am trying to run my app on my actual device. But it is complaining that no minSDK is compatible , any idea why that is the case? how do I resolve it?

Attached is my screenshot[image: Screenshot from Android Studio]

Comment: what is the android software version of your phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means that your phone uses an API for which you don't have installed the API in the sdk manager.
You have to go to the **SDK MANAGER** and then install the **sources** for the android version corresponding to the API of your phone.
Next, open the **build.gradle** file and put **minSdk *value of the minAPI installed*** instead of the value written before. 
Then you'll can run the app on your phone. 
In fact, you have to install all the API sources on which you want your app to be run.

Comment: My Android version on tablet is 5.02

Comment: So you need to install at least the sources for the API 21 in the sdk manager

Answer (score 1):

It means that the minimum SDK of your app is greater than the API level of the phone. Is the phone running a version of Android earlier than 4.0.3(API 15)?